# Parsing a dynamically loaded webpage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

I'm trying to parse https://www.flashscore.com/football/albania/ using Selenium in Python, but my webdriver often doesn't wait for the scores to finish loading.

Here's the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/football/albania/")
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
            lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
    print(driver.page_source)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Occasionally, this will print out source code for a flashscore page with a blank table (i.e. the driver does not wait for the scores to finish loading). I suspect that this is because some of the live scores on the page are dynamically loaded. Is there any way to improve my wait condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's an accept cookies button, so we have to click on that first.
2. I am using Explicit waits, `first presence of table` and then **visibility of it's main body.**

**Code :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.flashscore.com/football/albania/")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "live-table")))
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "section.event")))
    print(driver.page_source)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Output is certainly to long, so I would be able to post it here because **stackoverflow** won't allow me to do so.